# 'PolynomialFeatures' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I want to apply k-fold cross validation on the following regression models:

1. Linear Regression
2. Polynomial Regression
3. Support Vector Regression
4. Decision Tree Regression
5. Random Forest Regression

I am able to apply k-fold cross validation on all except polynomial regression which gives me this error `PolynomialFeatures' object has no attribute 'predict`. How to work around this issue. Also am I doing the job correctly, actually my main motive is to see which model is performing better, so is there a better way to do this job ??

```
# Compare Algorithms
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# load dataset
names = ['YearsExperience', 'Salary']
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv', names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[1:,0]
Y = array[1:,1]

X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

# prepare configuration for cross validation test harness
seed = 7

# prepare models
models = []
models.append(('LR', LinearRegression()))

models.append(('PR', PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)))
models.append(('SVR', SVR(kernel = 'rbf')))
models.append(('DTR', DecisionTreeRegressor()))
models.append(('RFR', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10)))

# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error'
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y.ravel(), cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)

# boxplot algorithm comparison
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `sklearn` you get polynomial regression by:

1. generating polynomial and interaction features on your original dataset by using [`sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)
2. running ordinary least squares Linear Regression on the transformed dataset by using [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

---

Toy example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

# Create linear regression object
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)

X_train = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = poly.fit_transform(X_test)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model.score(X_train, y_train))
```

Comment: Yup it worked. But, do you think tere is a better way to achieve my objective.

Comment: I think the line 'X_test = poly.fit_transform(X_test)' should be 'X_test = poly.transform(X_test)' right? Or is that just for other transformations? In my mind we always want to fit our transformation on the training data and then apply the fitting to both train and test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the changed part of the code if someone wants for reference :

```
# prepare models
models = []
models.append(('LR', LinearRegression()))

models.append(('PR', LinearRegression()))
models.append(('SVR', SVR(kernel = 'rbf')))
models.append(('DTR', DecisionTreeRegressor()))
models.append(('RFR', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10)))

# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error'
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    if name == 'PR':
        poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
        X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
        cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_poly, Y.ravel(), cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    else:
        cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y.ravel(), cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)

    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
```