# Polynomial fitting in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

i am trying to do a polynomial fit to my data and the output is a linear fit. i am trying to understand where my mistake is.

```
regr2 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
regr2.fit_transform(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)
regr2 = PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True)
regr2.fit_transform(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)

regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)

diabetes_y_pred = regr.predict(diabetes_X_test)

plt.scatter(diabetes_X_test, diabetes_y_test,  color='blue')
plt.plot(diabetes_X_test, diabetes_y_pred, color='red', linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doing it because you told it to.

```
regr = LinearRegression()
```

You are plotting "diabetes_y_pred," which comes from "regr.fit" and regr is defined above with "LinearRegression()."

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the help. How do i fix it?

Comment: Don't use scikit-learn much. My guess is  change diabetes_y_pred = regr.predict(diabetes_X_test) to diabetes_y_pred = regr2.predict(diabetes_X_test).

Comment: AttributeError: 'PolynomialFeatures' object has no attribute 'predict'                                                    getting this error when i run that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201362/polynomialfeatures-object-has-no-attribute-predict